# Is late May into Early June a good time to avoid the summer rush in London?

Tags: uk, london

I'd like to go to London for two weeks and take a few side trips in England and Wales. It's looking like from about May 21st to June 4th is when I can go.

Is that ahead of the Summer travel season, students partying, etc., or will I get caught up in that?

When is the peak Summer "madness" in London?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a wonderful time to visit England. I've visited the area in April-May several years ago and did a similar trip to what you're describing (southern England, Wales and spent a week in London itself), and it was awesome.

Note that this year you shouldn't be in London in July-September, unless you're interested in Olympics. That means that people who want to visit England not for Olympics will probably go there earlier than usual, and you'll have all the crowd you want to avoid right there with you.

But don't let it stop you, England is wonderful any time, especially late spring and early summer.

Comment: As well as that, watch for the Diamond Jubilee celebrations in early June. London is going to be extremely crowded, and don't forget the second bank holiday 5th June.

Comment: The best time to avoid the summer rush is early December.